# Scalatrasuite tests always failing in sbt, succeeds when running test in IDE

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatest, scalatra

I've been having a bit of an issue with ScalatraSuite unit testing with ScalaTest in sbt.

Versions that I am using:
Scalatra: 2.2.1
ScalaTest: 1.9.1
ScalatraScalatest: 2.2.1
Jetty: 9.0.2.v20130417
Scala: 2.10.1
SBT: 0.12.3

I had to extend ScalatraSuite and override the baseUrl method since Jetty v9+ I assume has some code changes where the getHost and getLocalPort have been re-factored so as a temporary workaround I use this in the meantime:

```
    trait TempScalatraSuite extends ScalatraSuite {

  override def baseUrl: String =
    server.getConnectors.headOption match {
      case Some(conn) =>
        val networkConn = conn.asInstanceOf[org.eclipse.jetty.server.NetworkConnector]
        val host = Option(networkConn.getHost) getOrElse "localhost"
        val port = networkConn.getLocalPort
        require(port > 0, "The detected local port is < 1, that's not allowed")
        "http://%s:%d".format(host, port)
      case None =>
        sys.error("can't calculate base URL: no connector")
    }
}
```

Now to the point, when executing unit tests in sbt all scalatra tests fail, an example of a test I'm trying to run (through sbt) with no luck:

```
 class MyTestServiceHttpServiceSpec extends TempScalatraSuite with WordSpec {

  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  addServlet(classOf[MyTestServiceHttpService], "/*")

  val contentType = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")

  "An invocation to /subscribeviaproxy" should {
    "yield a JSON result that contains a responseCode and a responseText when submitting a POST call" in {
      val jsonRequest = """{
                          "eventSource":"95100000",
                          "sourceNumber":"95100000",
                          "locale":"en_US"
                         }""""
      post("/subscribeviaproxy", jsonRequest.getBytes ,contentType) {
        log.info("responseBody is [{}]", body)
        status should equal (200)
        body should include ("responseCode")
        body should include ("responseMessage")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SBT always fails with the following errors:

```
> test-only com.foo.bar.http.server.mytestservice.MyTestServiceHttpServiceSpec
10:11:46.928  [INFO ] jetty-9.0.2.v20130417
10:11:46.995  [INFO ] started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1285302{/,file:/P:/git/mediationdal/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}
10:11:47.026  [INFO ] Started ServerConnector@5f57c0{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:49472}
10:11:47.777  [INFO ] Graceful shutdown org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@1c05bb5 by
10:11:47.781  [INFO ] Stopped ServerConnector@5f57c0{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0}
10:11:47.782  [INFO ] stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1285302{/,file:/P:/git/mediationdal/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
[info] LoyaltyPointsHttpServiceSpec:
[info] An invocation to /subscribeviaproxy
[info] - yield a JSON result that contains a responseCode and a responseText when submitting a POST call *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
[info]   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
[info]   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
[info]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:522)
[info]   ...
[error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         com.foo.bar.http.server.mytestservice.MyTestServiceHttpServiceSpec
[error] (test:test-only) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed May 8, 2013 10:11:47 AM
>
```

I can see the jetty server being started up and then being shut down, but I really don't understand why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Managed to fix the problem, all that needed to be done was set an option in SBT to fork the JVM for tests:

```
fork in Test := true,
```

tests ran like a charm afterwards.